# Merge daframes of different columns in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

#### I need to join dataframes with different columns created in a for-loop.

So this is the question in a simplified version. As you can see in the picture, I have made two dataframes.

1. In this dataframe, we have 5 columns, and the columns are not continuous (0,2,5 and 7 are missing).
2. Here we have 6 columns, not continuous(0,6,7 missing) and the columns itself does not completely match the first df.

[image]

#### What I need to do is :

- Step 1: create a new df with continuous column numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.
- Step 2: Add the rows of df1 and df2 corresponding to each column numbers. Whichever row whose column number does not have values should be a nan.

#### Note : This has to be done in a loop as I have thousands of dataframes to merge

#### So the resulting dataframe will be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
# store your dfs in an iterator
# df_list = [ ... ]

# the columns you want your final df to have
final_columns = range(9)

# add these columns with value None to your dfs if not there already
for df in df_list:
    
    for i in final_columns:
        if i not in df1.columns:
            df[i] = None

# merge all of your dfs together
final_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

final_df
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) + [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[34, 56, 66, 77, 77]], columns=[1, 3, 4, 6, 7])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[34, 56, 66, 77, 77, 66]], columns=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8])

# Collection of all DataFrames
dfs = (df1, df2)

# Concat
new_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).reindex(columns=np.arange(0, 9))

print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
    0   1     2   3   4     5     6     7     8
0 NaN  34   NaN  56  66   NaN  77.0  77.0   NaN
1 NaN  34  56.0  66  77  77.0   NaN   NaN  66.0
```